# Jquery .find() doesn't works in chrome but works in firefox

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

i'm using a validation plugin([position absolute](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)) and it's works in firefox but don't in chrome.

i detected issue is in .find() Jquery method, works different in both browsers.

take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/kwtp2/1/ for a detailed sample of this error.

please, run it on firefox then in chrome.

firefox: found 5 matches,
chrome: found 0 matches

any suggestion?

Kind Regards,
Rinaldo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't nest form elements. Your `#dialogForm` is being closed by the `form` immediately inside it (within the span `helpDialog`).

That this works in Firefox seems a fluke. Nesting forms is definitely not good form...no pun intended.

Comment: oh, my mistake, i copied & pasted #dialogForm content from other side and i don't take account of form inside a form...sorry for that... and really thanks!

Comment: No problem - that's a super confusing behavior for both browsers, and it's great that you caught it in Chrome. In a semi-related suggestion, `validate[required]` is a weird way to name classes when you could just do `validate required` with two CSS classes. Nothing is technically wrong with your approach, but `find('[class*=validate]')` seems more complicated and less clear than `find('.validate')`.

Answer (score 0):

@Rinaldo Sassaroli: See updated jsFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/kwtp2/7/